Group by or distinct for django to remove the row which has the duplicate column
I have table as follows:
Table A
    ID name score
     1 aaa   100
     2 bbb   200
     3 ccc   300
     4 bbb   100
     5 kkk   600
     6 ccc   300

Now name bbb and ccc is duplicated
So, I want to remove then and depict like this,
    ID name score
     1 aaa   100
     2 bbb   200
     3 ccc   300
     5 kkk   600

I found out that django model doesn't have groupby so, I guess need to use annotate or distinct
So my idea is like this below,
    MyModel.objects.annotate(Count('name'))

However it doesn't work as I hope.
Any help or hint?

Is this really related to the SQL language? I see no SQL above, is the answer expected to include SQL?

Exactly how do you deduplicate? You pick the first one? The minimum score? Something else?

Can you also share what database you use?

@Jarlh Ah, what I expect is code for django

@willeM_ Van Onsem I want to pick the first one and I use mysql 5.7

Then you can remove the  tag. (Answers to questions tagged with SQL should use ISO/IEC standard SQL.)

what's the problem with distinct?

@ZwickVitaly: it is distinct by a certain field. Django has tooling for this for PostgreSQL, not for a (generic) SQL database.

Distinct results based on a field are not trivial for a database other than postgresql in Django at the moment of writing.
But we can get this done with an Exists subquery:
from django.db.models import Exists, OuterRef

MyModel.objects.filter(
    ~Exists(
        MyModel.objects.filter(pk__lt=OuterRef('pk'), name=OuterRef('name'))
    )
)
We thus only generate a MyModel object in the result, of no other MyModel exists with the same name and a smaller primary key.
